# Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, abaqus

I am trying to import a dat file as an array in my python files. The dat file has 125 rows and 5 columns containing information about 125 ellipses (X and Y coordinate, small and large radii and angle).

This is the command I use:

```
X_centers, Y_Centers, Small_Radii, Large_radii, Angles=np.loadtxt('C:\Hamid\Ellipses-1.dat',unpack=True)
```

and that is the error I get

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: I think you need to pass a file object to the loadtxt function, not its name.

Comment: @muratgu It accepts both file pointer, and a filename string

Comment: what are the contents of your input file ? (Dont load the entire thing - just show a couple of rows as example)

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because the return from numpy.loadtext is more than 5 elements in length. Looking over the [ref doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) for numpy.loadtext, it sounds like it returns a single ndarray.

You can start debugging this with something like:

```
debug_it = np.loadtxt('C:\Hamid\Ellipses-1.dat',unpack=True)
print len(debug_it)
print debug_it.shape
```